# How to create new item in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Have a simply issue. Currently doing some pet-project and took nodejs api for it.
The API is written on nodejs and want to implements with my react-app.
But bumped into i can not create dummy date and to try testing the ui.

Here is method of creating:

```
.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var directory = _.pick(req.body, [
          'parentId',
          'name'
        ]
      )
      , parent = _.find(store.directories, function (dir) {
        return dir.id == directory.parentId
      })

    if (parent) {
      _.assign(directory, { id: idGenerator.getNext() })
      store.directories.push(directory)

      res.send(directory)
    } else {
      res.status(500).send('no parent')
    }
  })
```

The problem is i can not even to make a new  row in postman:

```
{
    "parentId": 1,
    "name": "some title"
}
```

Sending RAW => json and receiving: "Cannot POST /"

Comment: Please clarify "dummy date". Your code shows no dates

Comment: @OneCricketeer, i mean i want to receive some get results from api. so i wanted to create some date(dummy) as i've shown it like body-json and can not even to POST it.

Comment: Again, there's no dates here. `res.send(req.body)` will return the exact same request you made. Or you can `JSON.stringify` some random object. I don't understand why you need all this other code.